# What are the rules and laws for guards and loss prevention in NYC during Covid-19 in NYC?

Tags: new-york-state, covid-19, security, false-arrest

What are the rules and laws for guards and loss prevention in NYC during Covid-19 in NYC?

I've read that security guards and loss prevention are not allowed to detain people, essentially false imprisonment, over merely a suspecion of wrong doing.

Also, many stores now also place a sticker "paid" on all paid merchandise.

Say a person walks into a grocery store, buys, pays, and starts walking towards the exit, and a security guard is stopping people, not keeping 6 ft apart, and checking everyone's reciepts, and essentially breaking the social distancing rules, can that person ignore the security guard and continue walking out?